# Fail compile on purpose - Using source code of ongoing project

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor

I am using the sources of project that is in an ongoing development and constantly changes.

In a specific scenario, I must change the sources of the project to adapt it to my own needs.

I want to create a define (or set of defines) that will ensure that if I updated the sources of the external project, and I didn't added my changes again to the new version of the code,
I will fail the compile.
In other words - I want to protect my self from forgetting writing certain code

How would you recommend?

Using IAR workbench, compiling for TI25XX

Comment: We'd need to know more about your environment to do this. What toolchain/OS are you using? Dev Studio, Linux with makefiles, Xcode...? This question goes outside the scope of the code.

Comment: How about something like `#ifndef SOMETHING #error "Bad!" #endif`?

Comment: ... where `SOMETHING` is a version number you update in the external project's header file whenever you change it.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Exactly what I needed. add this as reply and I will mark it as answer

Comment: depending on exactly what type of system you are developing on, ***[This link on using #assert()](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/assertions.html)*** might apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the preprocessor directives `#ifndef` and `#error`:

```
#ifndef SOMETHING
  #error "Error message!"
#endif
```

If `SOMETHING` is not defined, the compilation will halt and `"Error message!"` will be displayed.

What `SOMETHING` actually is will have to be decided by you.  Perhaps it can be a version number<sup>1</sup>.

```
#if(CURRENT_VERSION < MINIMUM_VERSION)
  #error "Version out of date!"
#endif
```

<sup>1</sup> Suggested by [indiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19719/indiv).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you add a Preprocessor Error Directive, `#error`, inside a `#ifndef` block. For example:

```
#ifndef YOAVS_SPECIAL_CODE
#error "You forgot the code Yoav."
#endif
```